# Magento 2 How to remove zero count in Layernavigation

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

Magento 2 How to remove zero count in my custom filter i have lot of option with zero count how i will remove

Comment: do you want to remove just the count (only number) or the filter with count 0 ?

Comment: if count is zero that attribute should not come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this form Admin panel

1. Go to `Admin > Menu> Stores Attributes > Product`
2. choose the required attribute
3. then under `Storefront Properties` tab
4. Set *Use in Layered Navigation* to  **Filterable (with results)**
5. Reindex and Clear cache.

Hope this might help